# Visual studio staring on game and not Main screen

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-2022

[image]

I have a Visual studio project with a `.xaml` window where I have my main game, I am trying to make a menu with a start button but the game always runs before the Windows form.

My output is Windows application, not Windows form so I cannot select the form as the starting one of the application.

Is there any way around this?

[image]

I have tried selecting as startup but I cannot, I also don't have a program.cs that I have seen in other solutions.

Comment: Do you have time to check my answer?

Answer (score 0):

Judging from the file list, your file is a `WPF` project.

First create a new `Windows1.xaml` as the startup window.

Then modify `StartupUri="Mainwindow.xaml` to `StartupUri="Window1.xaml` in `App.xaml`.

The key code of the login window in `windows1.xaml` is:

```
private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    MainWindow mainWindow = new MainWindow();
    this.Hide();
    mainWindow.ShowDialog();
}
```